# Removing isolated roads using R?

Tags: openstreetmap, r

I am looking for ways to remove isolated roads R after filtering out the roads of interest (see attached image). These roads were not isolated in the original .osm file, but became isolated after some filters were applied. They might have been isolated after filtering as they might have been mis-tagged in the original data.

[image]

The road data (.osm file) is obtained from [Geofabrik](https://www.geofabrik.de/data/download.html), and the desired location selected using a combination of osmosis and using the osmar package in R (see code snippet).

```
## import osmar
library(osmar)
## Import road.osm file
muc <- get_osm(complete_file(), osmsource_file(file="road.osm"))
## discard paths with value 'footway' as attribute
hw_ids <- find(muc, way(tags(k == "highway" & v!="footway")))
hw_ids <- find_down(muc, way(hw_ids))
hw <- subset(muc, ids = hw_ids)
## plot
plot(hw, col= "black")
```

Any help using some combination of osmosis and R to remove these isolated roads is preferred. I have seen a solution on gis that suggested the use of ArcGIS, but I do not have access to ArcGIS.

Comment: Did you consider getting intersected lines then extract non intersected from filtered ?

Comment: As far as I know, looking for intersections will only allow me to remove straight line specks, but bigger isolated roads would still have intersection. I have no idea how to build a function that groups intersecting roads into a 'network' though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution using the `igraph` package:

```
library(osmar)
## Import road.osm file
muc <- get_osm(complete_file(), osmsource_file(file="path/to/road.osm"))
## discard paths with value 'footway' as attribute
hw_ids <- find(muc, way(tags(k == "highway" & v!="footway")))
hw_ids <- find_down(muc, way(hw_ids))
hw <- subset(muc, ids = hw_ids)

## plot
plot(hw, col= "black")

## import igraph
require(igraph)
myGraph = as_igraph(hw)
# create multiple graphs (for connected roads)
dec = decompose(myGraph)

# find main network (the one with the most connected roads)
maxEdges = 0
mainNetworkPointer = 1
for(i in 1:length(dec)){
  if(length(as_edgelist(dec[[i]])) > maxEdges){
    maxEdges = length(as_edgelist(dec[[i]]))
    mainNetworkPointer = i
  }
}

# get all edges from main network
listOfEdges = as_edgelist(dec[[mainNetworkPointer]])
# get the IDs
mainNetworkIDs = unique(as.numeric(listOfEdges))

# Create new network osmar subset with main network IDs
main_ids <- find_up(hw, node(mainNetworkIDs))
main = subset(muc, ids = main_ids)

## plot
plot(main, col= "black")
```

Note that in my code example the "main" network is determined by the maximal number of connected roads. You might want to determine it by some ID or other criteria that need to be adjusted if intended.

Here an example with all roads:

[image: all_roads]

Without isolated roads (using above code):

[image: no_isolated]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but there is a small typo -- I think it should be: "main = subset(muc, ids = main_ids)", not "new_ids". I had a similar idea, but I could not get past beyond using as_igraph(). I didn't know how to extract useful information from it, and I was contemplating whether to ask another question. Fortunately, your answer addressed that as well!

Comment: Yes, that was a typo.